# selectively picking date from the note field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to selectively pick date from the note field.The position where the date is entered in a note field is not constant. Is there a possibility to filter the date based on the "`/`" that appears in the `yyyy/mm/dd` part?

Comment: Note field? What do you mean?

Comment: You will need to use Regular expressions and search for: 4 digits, a slash, 2 digits, a slash, and two digits. Needless to say, anything matching that pattern will be considered as a date though.

Comment: if I use this code it picks the date at the beginning of the note field-(note field is a note typed in by a provider.  "SELECT  LEFT(fieldname, 8) As date
      
  FROM [server].[dbo].[tablename]"

Comment: There can be multiple Dates enetered in the note field and I am trying to pick them selectively- is this impossible to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick the date in a string which is in the format YYYY/MM/DD and there is no slash (/) anywhere else in the string other than at the date, then below code will work.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100) = 'Date is entered here 2017/11/23 and I should pick it'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('/',@string,0)-4,10)
```

Comment: That would not work since the `/` character could be anywhere besides a date part.

Comment: Yeah @FDavidov, this will work only if the string contain / in the date